# A or An in "a (relatively) obscure meaning"?

Tags: grammaticality, articles, indefinite-articles

I've just come across this sentence here at "english.stackexchange.com".

> "The writer should have taken care not to hide such a (relatively) obscure meaning underneath an obviously silly one."

Could the indefinite article "an" be used here, instead of "a" ?

Comment: No. The next word starts with a consonant sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> - *The writer should have taken care not to hide such* ***a*** *(relatively) obscure meaning underneath an obviously silly one.*
>
> Could the indefinite article "an" be used here, instead of "a"?

The answer is no, that it should be an "a".

The choice of the article--"a" versus "an"--happens to be the only systematic exception to the general rule that a *parenthesised element* doesn't affect the grammar of the sentence.

Related info in a vetted grammar source, the 2002 *CGEL* on page 1748:

> **4 Parentheses**
>
> In their primary use parentheses occur in pairs and enclose what we will call a **parenthesised element.** Their function is to present that element as extraneous to a minimal interpretation of the text, as inessential material that can be omitted without affecting the well-formedness and without any serious loss of information. [fn 16] . . .
>
> footnote 16: The only systematic exception to this generalization is that when the indefinite article precedes a parenthesized element its form (as *a* or *an*) depends on the properties of the first word within the parentheses: *She made an (interminable) movie about a (supposedly endangered) owl.* The choice between *a* and *an* is made on a phonological basis (see Ch. 18, &6.4), and always on the basis of the sentence as it would sound if read aloud with the parenthesized element included.

Note that 2002 *CGEL* is the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL).

Comment: Cool! An exception to a rule! I write it like that, but didn't know there was a specific exception for it. I just assumed it was like reading aloud. An interesting aside, I do it the other was around as well: *an (ill-mannered) comment*, for example.